# Assumption that $\delta q'$ is small in the derivation of Euler-Lagrange equations.

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I have never completely understood the justification of this step in the derivation of the E-L equation:

$\delta L = L(q + \delta q, q' + \delta q', x) - L(q, q', x) = \partial_q L \delta q + \partial_{q'} L \delta q'$

This is only valid when both $\delta q$ and $\delta q'$ are small. Now $\delta q$ is small by assumption, but $\delta q'$ is completely determined by 
$\delta q$, so the smallness of $\delta q'$ needs to be implied by the smallness of $\delta q$. However, if $\delta q$ has high frequency components (eq $\delta q = \epsilon sin(x/\epsilon)$ for a small $\epsilon$) then $\delta q'$ will not be small even though $\delta q$ is. I imagine this can be fixed by having additional assumtions on $\delta q$ like that it is of the form $\epsilon f$ where $\epsilon$ is small and $f$ is just a suitably nice function,
but the explanations I have seen do not make such assumptions explicit.

Also I have never seen a good explanation of the properties $\delta$ operator.
In the usual E-L derivation it also seems to be assumed that $\delta (q') = (\delta q)'$. I can convince myself of that informally, but it is something that would seem worth explaining. Is there a good reference that goes into the $\delta$ operator in some depth.

EDIT

When I first asked my question I was forgetting about Lanczos *Variational Principles of Mechanics* which goes into the $\delta$ notation in some length.
Now that I have gone back to Lanczos, I know a little bit more, but it is still far from clear, despite Lanczos's heroic efforts.

The responses seem to agree on the idea that $\delta$ is not an independent entity, but more of a naming convention, making $\delta L$ and $\delta q$ atomic names. This makes some sense to me, but it contradicts Lanczos in *Variational Principles of Mechanics*, where he uses the term $\delta$-process. He even writes things like $\delta^2 F$ and $\delta \int F$ and even has the equivalent of
$\delta (q') = (\delta q)'$ above as equation 29.3, together with a derivation.
Lanczos stresses the notion of *virtual displacement* . At one point he says that $\delta u$ is a virtual change while $du$ is an actual change. Unfortunately I have no clue what he is getting at, but virtual displacement seems to be the concept I am missing. I have found
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_displacement, but I am not really parsing that either. However, the abstract of [Subhankar Ray, J. Shamanna, Virtual Displacement in Lagrangian Dynamics](http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0410123) sounds promising:

> ... However, the definition
>   of virtual displacement is rarely made precise and often
>   seems vague and ambiguous to students. In this article
>   we attempt a more systematic and precise definition,
>   which not only gives one a qualitative idea of virtual
>   displacement, but also allows one to quantitatively
>   express the same for any given constrained system. ...

Sounds like what the doctor ordered.

Comment: I do not think that $\delta$ is an operator. At least in the proofs that I read, $\delta q$ refers to some function, hence $\delta(q')$ does not mean anything, unlike $\delta q'=(\delta q)'$.

Comment: I tried to explain notation in my answer. Personally, to consider $\delta$ as an operator is not so clear to me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: the basic assumption is that the Lagrangian $L(q(x),q'(x),x)$ is differentiable at $y:=(q(x),q'(x),x)$ and the variation $\delta L$ expresses the differentiability, in a suitable limit.

In other words, we are considering the increment ( $h$ is just a vector in $\mathbb R^3$, for all $x$, but the components $\delta q$ and $\delta q'$ are **functions** of $x$)

$$h:=(\delta q,\delta q',0)$$

and looking at

$$L(y+h)-L(y)=\langle \nabla L(y),h\rangle+O(\|h\|);~~(*)$$

the gradient $\nabla L(y)$ of $L$ at $y$ is

$$\nabla L(y)=\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial q},\frac{\partial L}{\partial q'},\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}\right) $$

and, by definition,

$$y+h=(q(x)+\delta q,q'(x)+\delta q',x).$$

- **Remark**: boundary conditions

In variational problems, the vector $h$ is not completely arbitrary: in fact, if we  consider small variations _(i.e. $\delta q$) of the function $q:x\mapsto q(x)$ we need to impose boundary conditions on the components of $h$: such conditions are depending on the specific variational problem under exam. They are motivated by the variational approach and usually "kill" unfriendly boundary terms (at least in classical variational problems: in quantum field theory one can accept and subsequently work with boundary terms).

For example, in presence of the variational problem

$$S[q]:=\int_a^b L(q(x),q'(x),x)dx $$

we would be interested in all small variations $\delta q$ of $q=q(x)$ s.t.  $\delta q(a)=\delta q(b)=0$.

If we expand $(*)$ using the definition of gradient and scalar product, we arrive at

$$L(q(x)+\delta q,q'(x)+\delta q',x)-L(q(x),q'(x),x)=\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}\delta q+\frac{\partial L}{\partial q'}\delta q'+O(\|h\|). $$

- **Remark**: parameters

  In some books and papers it is customary to define the small variations $\delta q$ as

$$\delta q:=\epsilon\varphi, $$
$$\delta q':=\epsilon\varphi' $$

where $\varphi$ is any function satisfying suitable boundary conditions, and $\epsilon$ is a parameter. In this setting we are considering the increment

$$h=(\epsilon\varphi,\epsilon\varphi',0)$$

around $y=(q(x),q'(x),x)$ and the first variation $\delta L$ of $L$ is defined as

$$\delta L:=\frac{dL}{d\epsilon}|_{\epsilon=0}:=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}
\frac{L(q(x)+\epsilon\varphi,q'(x)+\epsilon\varphi',x)-L(q(x),q'(x),x)-\epsilon\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}\varphi+\frac{\partial L}{\partial q'}\varphi'\right)+O(\epsilon^2)}{\epsilon}. $$

I personally find this notation quite good.

Comment: That is all very clear. My problem is that the books I have seem do not explicitly define δq := ϵφ, so I do not see how they exclude small but rapidly oscillating δq, which could give a non-small δq′. So I have just always wondered if I am missing something here.

Comment: I had (have) the same problems, as most of the books manipulate the symbols $\delta q$ and $\delta q'$ formally and I get lost into the flow of formal manipulations until my head falls on the desk

Comment: If you find the answer useful, feel free to flag it. Thanks!

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I did not down vote.

Comment: The Calculus of Variations by Brunt defines the first variation of $S[q]$ explicitly right before Eq. (2.6).